# Demo project for STM NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q board?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

This [NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-h745zi-q.html) development board comes with a demo project that blinks the LEDs at different rates. One LED  blinks at the time and as I press the user button the on LED changes. It goes from red/fast to yellow/medium then to green/slow. The documentation for the board ([UM2408](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-h745zi-q.html#documentation)) says:

*The software demonstration and the several software examples, that allow the user to use the Nucleo features, are available at the [www.st.com/stm32nucleo](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards.html) web page.*

I can not find the demo project in that page. I downloaded and installed [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) which downloaded a built-in version of [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) and I think [STM32CubeH7](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubeh7.html). I can see in STM32CubeIDE that I can choose examples for this board, when I make a new project, but none of them seem to be the preloaded project that blinks the LEDs at different rates.

Does anyone know where I can find this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

STM tech support point me to the source code. Here is the link in case someone is interested:

https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeH7/blob/master/Projects/NUCLEO-H745ZI-Q/Demonstrations/readme.txt